# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am creating the registration form Spring boot Application with spring thymeleaf. after i run the project i got the following errors

StackTrace Error i attched below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentService': Error creating bean with name 'seviceIMPL': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.espring.ecommerce.repo.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.espring.ecommerce.Entity.Student
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
```

what i tried so far i attached below

**studentController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Home Page");
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student std, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        studentService.save(std);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
    
}
```

**Student**

```
public class Student {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String course;
    private String image;
```

**StudentService**

```
@Service
public class SeviceIMPL implements StudentService {
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repo;
    @Override
    public void save(Student std) {
        repo.save(std);
    }
}
```

**SeviceIMPL**

```
@Service
public class SeviceIMPL implements StudentService {
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repo;
    @Override
    public void save(Student std) {
        repo.save(std);
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository  extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {



}
```

Comment: Try adding `@Entity` to Student class.

Comment: i wrote the @Entity student class i got the error Persistent entity 'Student' should have primary key